# how to get the value in array from database laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to extract the values from array in a column from database. For example, my value in my permission column is `["Create","Edit","Delete]`. So when I `dd($user->permission)` it would return like that. How can I get the value from it so that I can return the result in a list. I have really no idea for now and what I cannot find similar question to mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a task for [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators). Simply add to your model:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'permission' => 'array',
];
```